# Image Store Issue

Tags: assets

Dear Craft Users/Developers

We have inherited a customer on our server platform using CraftCMS 2.7.4. They had their site before moving to us hosted with images using Rackspace via the CraftCMS Pro Agents for RackSpace. The new hosting is based on nice fast SSD and we have created a second Asset Store using Local Folder. The Posts have been relinked to assets stored on the new local asset store. The problem we have seems to be when we tell craft that the original store is no longer required. The moment we delete the original store we get lots of red references to missing assets in the backend Admin. Yet the site all looks great with no missing images even after full cache empty. We have PHPAdmin access to the database and I can see there are ID's for the two stores. Not sure how to progress as at some point we will want to cancel the account with Rack Space. Any help gratefully appreciated

John James

Comment: After you change all of the paths to point to the local asset source and delete the Rackspace volume, try running the Update Asset Index tool from Settings in the Control Panel.